# Why is Netbeans + Xdebug showing repetitive results in Variables pane?

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug, netbeans6.8

I just started using Netbeans to debug PHP apps, but when I inspect any object it has the CLASSNAME printed over and over, making it very difficult to understand the contents of an object. See the image below to see what I am talking about.  Anybody know what is going on?

[image]

Here are some details that might be important...
Netbeans version 6.8
PHP 5.2.9
Xdebug version 2.1.0 beta.  Here is my xdebug config from php.ini:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension_ts="C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.2.9-2\ext\php_xdebug-2.1.0beta3-5.2-vc6.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
```

If I can't get this resolved I will be flopping back to Eclipse (which seems to be soooooo slow!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, looks like this is a problem with the version of xdebug that I was using.  Xdebug 2.1.0 beta has a new pseudo-property called CLASSNAME that Netbeans doesn't quite know how to handle yet.  I was able to get around this by using xdebug 2.0.5.

In case someone is interested:
Here is the Netbeans bug report: http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=182148.
And here is the xdebug bug report: http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=518